# Can iOS sign in social account within app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, google-plus

I would like to make a social login function on the iOS application but I don't want to switch user to safari/Facebook app, Google +app etc when use connect more social account.
I see the Flipboard app (iOS) can do that, when the user select "Add Google+" the current view controller push the Google+ sign in view controller to this screen so user can login on this without switch to the safari or Google App.

Thanks,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screens you posted are completely custom, so they are probably made by the developer of the app. iOS offers **Social.framework**, which allows you to login into **Facebook**, **Twitter**, **Flickr** and **Vimeo** using user's global iOS settings. I'm not aware of any other services available in core iOS, maybe there are more options in other markets. Those services will not redirect you to another app but will login with popups.

However many of these services provide their own SDK's, or there are community SDK's available, which wrap their API's in Objective-C or Swift. Such services include Facebook, who developers their own [SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), while for Twitter there is a [community wrapper](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) by Nicolas Seriot available. Similar to these two, you can find libraries for most of the services.

Facebook's SDK will redirect you to Facebook only if Facebook is installed and to Safari only if URL schema is defined in your .plist file (like Anbu Karthik mentioned). In that way even Facebook SDK will open a webview in a popup. Other libraries are working in a similar way, this is due to OAuth2 standards, making logins more secure.

*The only problem remains that all those libraries include a load of functionality, but you usually only need the login capabilities. That is why I started working on [**AuthKit**](https://github.com/Legoless/AuthKit), which will provide out of the box login capabilities to most of the popular online services. Sadly, currently it is not stable yet for production use.*

**It is up to you to create UI for the login and integrate those services.**

Comment: Thank you,
Follow you suggestion, I have found some libs can help me do that AFOAuth2Client is a sample.

Answer (score 0):

iOS Native Login Dialog

The iOS native login dialog is a feature of Apple's Facebook integration. If people have logged in to Facebook via their iOS settings, they can be authenticated into your app using these credentials. This is a device-level authentication, which means that a person has to log in to your app on every device they use.

Advantages:

100% native, fast.
**The login flow doesn't transition off your app.**

Disadvantages:

Can only be used if people using your app log in to Facebook via iOS 6+.
No visual cue, ex: profile picture of the person being authenticated.
Does't provide a privacy selector to the user when publish permissions are requested.
Special considerations:

Using the iOS native Login Dialog requires that you have certain special considerations when asking for permissions. You can read about it in the iOS integration guide.

For more details see [Facebook Native Login Dialog For iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.1#dialogs-iosnative)